# How old will jack be in $5$ years

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

The question is

> Jack is now $14$ years older than Bill. If in $10$ years Jack will be twice as old as Bill, how old will Jack be in $5$ years? (Ans = $23$)

Here is how I am solving it could anyone tell me where I might be going wrong ?
\begin{equation}
J = 14 + B \tag{i}\label{i}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
J+10 = 2B \tag{ii}\label{ii}
\end{equation}

So by inserting \eqref{i} in \eqref{ii} we get$$24=B,$$so Jack is $38$, and after $5$ years he will be $38+5=43$ years old.

Comment: The RHS in ii should be $2(B+10)$.

Comment: In future, please use `>` instead of `>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second equation, you are ten years in the future. With $J$ and $B$ representing Jack and Bill's *present* age respectively, Bill's age ten years from now is $B+10$ and Jack's age ten years from now is $J+10$. In your second equation, you had the latter term correct but not the former. Your second equation should be $J+10=2(B+10)$.

Comment: Oh yes. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing it out